# Audacity installation error

Tags: linux, installation, audacity

Getting following error on installing audacity in linux:

```
export/ExportPCM.cpp: In member function ‘bool ExportPCM::AddStrings(AudacityProject*, SNDFILE*, Tags*, int)’:
export/ExportPCM.cpp:740: error: ‘SF_STR_GENRE’ was not declared in this scope
export/ExportPCM.cpp:764: error: ‘SF_STR_TRACKNUMBER’ was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [export/ExportPCM.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/audacity/audacity-src-2.0.5/src'
make: *** [audacity] Error 2
```

Can any one help me in fixing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error. The following is my solution:

From the first error line:

> export/ExportPCM.cpp: In member function ‘bool ExportPCM::AddStrings(AudacityProject*, SNDFILE*, Tags*, int)’:

we see that it is caused by libsndfile. Therefore, you just need to compile the latest libsndfile. Download tarball here http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/#Download

After that, you compile audacity again and compilation will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error when *compiling* that package, not during *installation*. It most likely is the result of some version incompatibility between the code you try to compile and some development version installed on your system which is referred to by the code. You will have to find out what packages usually declare those constants and adjust your versions accordingly.

Apart from that: sure you want to make such a "wild" installation? Typically packages are installed using your systems software management system these days. That is much easier, more robust and allows easy upgrades to newer versions. Audacity should be available for most GNU/Linux distributions.